# Controlling volume with buttons

Tags: android

I want to be able to control the volume with on screen buttons (A plus and a minus)

I'm using the following in the OnClick method:

```
        case R.id.bMinus:
        currentRingerVolume = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
        newvolume(-1);
        audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                volume, 0);
        break;
    case R.id.bPlus:
        currentRingerVolume = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
        newvolume(1);
        audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                volume, 0);
```

newvolume is a method I want to use so I don't go below volume 0 or above max volume

```
private void newvolume(int i) {

    /*

    currentRingerVolume = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
    maxRingerVolume = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);


     */
    if(volume != maxRingerVolume){
        volume = currentRingerVolume + i;
        volumeInt.setText(volume.toString());
        Log.v("tag ", "v:" + volume + " cv:" + currentRingerVolume);

    }
    if (currentRingerVolume == 0 && i == -1){
        volume = 0;
        volumeInt.setText(currentRingerVolume.toString());
        Log.v("tag ", "v:" + volume + " cv:" + currentRingerVolume);

    }
}
```

In logcat my cv (currentRingerVolume) is always 8 and my v(Volume) only varies between 5-8

I'm also getting this in the logcat

```
12908-12914/com.asdf.wasd D/dalvikvm﹕ JIT code cache reset in 0 ms (4096 bytes 2/0)
    01-19 13:35:11.779  12908-12914/com.asdf.wasd D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 1204K, 29% free 19409K/27312K, paused 7ms+14ms, total 103ms
    01-19 13:35:12.940  12908-12914/com.asdf.wasd I/dalvikvm﹕ hprof: dumping heap strings to "[DDMS]".
    01-19 13:35:17.224  12908-12914/com.asdf.wasd I/dalvikvm﹕ hprof: heap dump completed (20349KB)
    01-19 13:35:17.244  12908-12908/com.adsf.wasd I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 300 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Is it because you are getting from AudioManager.STREAM_RING but setting to AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to set the volume from the same stream you get it from:

```
case R.id.bMinus:
    currentRingerVolume = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
    newvolume(-1);
    audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING,
            volume, 0);
    break;
case R.id.bPlus:
    currentRingerVolume = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
    newvolume(1);
    audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING,
            volume, 0);
```

Also, this volume adjustment code will not work if the current volume is at the max and you are trying to reduce it. Change to this:

```
if((volume != maxRingerVolume) || (i == -1)){
    volume = currentRingerVolume + i;
    volumeInt.setText(volume.toString());
    Log.v("tag ", "v:" + volume + " cv:" + currentRingerVolume);

}
```

A more easy to read way to rearrange your code might be something like this:

```
volume = currentRingerVolume + i; // apply change
if(volume > maxRingerVolume)
    volume = maxRingerVolume;   // clamp to max
if(volume < 0)
    volume = 0; // clamp to min

// output debug information:
volumeInt.setText(volume.toString());
Log.v("tag ", "v:" + volume + " cv:" + currentRingerVolume);
```